# Chansing the subcategory of app in the AppStore will reset the ranking?

Tags: app-store

I got one game in the Trivia subcategory. (2nd subcategory)

I would like to change to "Family" subcategory.

The new subcategory will reset the ranking ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is specified in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) about this , but change the **second** category should not lose the ranking of your App

Answer (score 0):

Ya, I got one friend who tried the same thing around a year ago, and in his case , the ranking was rested but yet the comments other people made still existed. I dont know what apple is doing these days after the ios 7 refresh to the AppStore but you should write to Apple about this to know more.